# Expanding and collapsing a nav on mouse enter/leave, REACT

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a nav bar at the side of my page. I got it via a react bootstrap website so the class names etc are pre loaded. Instead of having a toggle hamburger logo to expand/collapse the nav I wish to do it on mouse enter/leave. Below is my attempt so far, I have made 2 handlers for both mouse enter and leave and i used inspect element so list the class names for the nav when it is both expanded and collapsed.

Then I attempted to give the nav these class names depending on whether the mouse is in or out of the nav, but it doesn't work :( help pls

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {

    let sideNav;

    const mouseEnter = e => {
      sideNav = "sideNav sidenav---sidenav---_2tBP sidenav---expanded---1KdUL";
      console.log("Mouse entered");
      return sideNav;
    }    

    const mouseLeave = e => {
      sideNav = "sidenav---sidenav---_2tBP sidenav---collapsed---LQDEv";
      console.log("mouse left");
      return sideNav;
    }

    return (
      <div className="App container">
        <div>
          <SideNav 
            onMouseEnter={mouseEnter} 
            onMouseLeave={mouseLeave}
            className={this.sideNav}
            onSelect={(selected) => {
                // Add your code here
            }}
          >
            <SideNav.Toggle  />
            <SideNav.Nav  defaultSelected="home">
                <NavItem eventKey="home">
                    <NavIcon>
                        <Link to="/"><img src={Dash}/></Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/">Dashboard</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="sites">
                    <NavIcon>
                      <Link to="/sites"><img src={Site} /></Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/sites">Sites</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="tours">
                  <NavIcon>
                    <Link to="/tours"><img src={Tour}/></Link>
                  </NavIcon>
                  <NavText>
                      <Link to="/tours">Tours</Link>
                  </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="media">
                    <NavIcon>
                      <Link to="/media"><img src={Media}/> </Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/media">Media</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="newSite">
                    <NavIcon>
                        <Link to="/newSite/details"><img src={NewSite} /></Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/newSite/details">Add new Site</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="profile">
                    <NavIcon>
                        <Link to="/profile"><img src={Profile} /></Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/profile">Profile</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>

            </SideNav.Nav>
          </SideNav>
        </div>
        <Routes />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I think you are almost done. I think you must set the class in the state and use the state to update the class on the `SideNav` or where you need to use it

Comment: You are creating your functions inside your render function. That means they will be override on every render.

Comment: @luissmg I'm not sure how I would go about doing that sorry

Comment: Where do you want to toggle the class (the exact element) and what is the lib you are using for the `SideNav`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use sideNav in your component's state, since it's the react way to re-render a element. Everytime you use setSate, react search for changes in the code to show what you want. When you just update your variable, react doesn't know that. So your code will problably work like if you do this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {
        sideNav: ''
      }
  }
    const mouseEnter = e => {
      this.setState({sideNav: "sideNav sidenav---sidenav---_2tBP sidenav---expanded---1KdUL"});
      console.log("Mouse entered");
    }    

    const mouseLeave = e => {
      this.setState({sideNav: "sidenav---sidenav---_2tBP sidenav---collapsed---LQDEv"});
      console.log("mouse left");
    }
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App container">
        <div>
          <SideNav 
            onMouseEnter={mouseEnter} 
            onMouseLeave={mouseLeave}
            className={this.state.sideNav}
            onSelect={(selected) => {
                // Add your code here
            }}
          >
            <SideNav.Toggle  />
            <SideNav.Nav  defaultSelected="home">
                <NavItem eventKey="home">
                    <NavIcon>
                        <Link to="/"><img src={Dash}/></Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/">Dashboard</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="sites">
                    <NavIcon>
                      <Link to="/sites"><img src={Site} /></Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/sites">Sites</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="tours">
                  <NavIcon>
                    <Link to="/tours"><img src={Tour}/></Link>
                  </NavIcon>
                  <NavText>
                      <Link to="/tours">Tours</Link>
                  </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="media">
                    <NavIcon>
                      <Link to="/media"><img src={Media}/> </Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/media">Media</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="newSite">
                    <NavIcon>
                        <Link to="/newSite/details"><img src={NewSite} /></Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/newSite/details">Add new Site</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="profile">
                    <NavIcon>
                        <Link to="/profile"><img src={Profile} /></Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/profile">Profile</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>

            </SideNav.Nav>
          </SideNav>
        </div>
        <Routes />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Also, you can see here how this works https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: This was exactly what I said on the comments :)

Comment: @luissmg You should have answered! :)